# Is it possible to interconnect multiple distant machines on the same LAN without using VPN?

Tags: networking

I have 3 different servers in different locations (1 in my company and the other 2 are in 2 different cities). I want to make them communicate on the same LAN without using VPN. Do you know of a solution I can implement?
The idea is to find a solution that will not impact performance or security.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an SSH tunnel but a VPN would be the best solution for what you're trying to accomplish. At least based on the information you have provided.